# Run specific spec files on cypress docker-compose setup

Tags: docker-compose, cypress

I have a docker-compose file to run cypress tests, but I see that it is identifying all the spec files in the integration folder and running the tests. I wanted to run a subset of the spec files . for example: only one specific spec file.

I tried with command: and the cypress run the specific file which did not help. Is there any way to run a specific spec file with the docker-compose setup.

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
  cypress:
    image: 'cypress/included:6.6.0'
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_environment=test
    working_dir: /test
    volumes:
      - ./:/test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the Dockerfile it uses entrypoint, so you can use a command parameter in your compose file to run specific file

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
  cypress:
    image: 'cypress/included:6.6.0'
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_environment=test
    working_dir: /test
    volumes:
      - ./:/test
    command: "--spec /test/integration/mytest.js"
```